# Does Blockapps allow contract deployment to the Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockapps

I've been exploring Blockapps' Strato & bloc APIs and deploying sample contracts to their private blockchain, but I was wondering how I can use this to deploy a contract to the actual Ethereum blockchain. Any links to documentation on this (beyond the Blockapps API documentation) or examples would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Blockapps platform helps developer to build Proof of Concepts (PoCs) so you could use it to write and test your smartcontract before deploying it in the pblic ethereum network. it is an easy way to run a local development/testing environement. Once you are ready you could deploy your contract to the public network by indicating the right API url read https://github.com/blockapps/blockapps-js#blockapps-profiles

*I didn't try before to use it to deploy a contract to the public network so if it works please confirm it*