# Is it possible to deploy contracts to live ethereum network using Blockapps?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockapps

I've been exploring Blockapps Strato & bloc APIs and tried deploying contracts to their private blockchain. I now started was wondering how I can use this to deploy a contract to the actual Ethereum blockchain. Any links to documentation on this (beyond the Blockapps API documentation) or examples would be very welcome.

Comment: look at this answer here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/does-blockapps-allow-contract-deployment-to-the-ethereum-blockchain